# Finding the URL of the previous page, which is not in the web history

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome extension relating to xkcd, and I want to be able to tell if the current page came from the [random button](http://dynamic.xkcd.com/random/comic/). Unfortunately, that URL (http://dynamic.xkcd.com/random/comic/) is not found in the web history and is not available with `document.referrer`. Is there a way to get the previous page even if it is not in the web history? or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you from doing this directly. The random page is a `307` redirect, which is invisibly handled by the browser, but you can make it more visible. I am not sure what you want to do with the knowledge that it came from the random button but consider the following example:

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Chrome webrequest test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "A test for webrequest",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>","webRequest","webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bgp.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://xkcd.com/*"],
    "js": ["xkcdInject.js"]
  }]
}
```

**bgp.js**

```
var requestIds = [];

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(function(details){
  requestIds.push(details.requestId);
},
{urls: ["http://dynamic.xkcd.com/random/comic/"]});

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details){
  var n = requestIds.indexOf(details.requestId);
  if(n > -1){
    setTimeout(function(){
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId,{random:"true"});
    },1000); 
    requestIds.splice(n,1);
  }
},
{urls: ["http://xkcd.com/*"]},["responseHeaders"]);
```

**xkcdIject.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  if(message.random == 'true')
    console.log("This page came from the random button.");
});
```

In this example, it is listening for use of the random button and then sending knowledge of this use to the tab in question. With this, your tab knows if it came from the random button or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a security limitation, you will only have access to the referrer and random is handled server side returning just the new page, its a function (so to speak) rather than a page you've visited.

My only suggestion is check if the referrer is the same domain (xkcd) but not a sequential url

ie current url is xkcd.com/189 was referrer /188 or /190 otherwise assume its a random

Comment: That's what I was afraid I might have to do.